# How to get the same instance of a class everywhere it's used inside the object

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

A little clearer than the question. I want to get the same instance of a class everywhere the class is used inside of an object. I'm using google guice through out the project. Here's an example to better explain.

```
@Singleton class A {
    C c;
    D d;

    @Inject public A(C c, D d){
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }

}

class B {
    Map<Integer,String> hashmap = new Hashmap<>();

    public String getInfo(Integer number){
        return hashmap.get(number);
    }
}

@Singleton class C {
    Class B; 
    @Inject public C( B b){
        this.b = b;
    }
}

@Singleton class D {
    Class B; 
    @Inject public D(B b){
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

So each time  a new `A` is created. I want that `A`'s `C` and `D` to share the same `B` , but I don't want all `A` 's to share one `B` . Also `C` and `D` are being injected into the constructor and A is a Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your own scope.

To do that, read the [Custom Scopes](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomScopes) page on Guice's wiki.